# Full calendar restrict agenda week view with start and end time

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) plugin. I've a requirement to display fixed timings in agenda week and agenda day view . i.e I have to display (06 AM to 06 PM) only. I have not found any configuration options to do so. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is `minTime` and `maxTime`. Eg Below:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    minTime: "06:00:00",
    maxTime: "18:00:00"
});
```